# One-way relationships with ember-data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to set up a simple platform for employees to give feedback to each other. I am using ember-data (from beta branch).

**Models**:

```
App.Employee = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr()
})

App.Feedback = DS.Model.extend({
    text: DS.attr(),
    employee: DS.belongsTo('employee', {async: true})
})
```

**Router** (simplyfied):

```
App.Router.map(function(){
    this.resource('profile', {path: 'profile/profile_id'})
})

App.ProfileRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
     model: function(params){
        return this.store.find('employee', params.profile_id);
     }
})
```

**Data**:

```
App.Employee.reopenClass({
  FIXTURES: [
    { id: 1, name: 'Trek'},
    { id: 2, name: 'Tom'}
  ]
});

App.Feedback.reopenClass({
  FIXTURES: [
    { id: 1, text: 'Topic1', employee: 1},
    { id: 2, text: 'Topic2', employee: 2},
    { id: 3, text: 'Topic3', employee: 1},
    { id: 4, text: 'Topic4', employee: 2}
  ]
});
```

I can't get a list of feedbacks to display in the template `profile`.

**Template**:

```
{{#each feedback in model.feedback}}
    {{feedback.text}}
{{/each}}
```

I can't figure out, what I'm doing wrong.

Should I specify `feedbacks: DS.hasMany('feedback')` under `App.Employee`? Or should I do this through the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There is a typo in Router description (missed colon before 'profile_id'):

   ```
   App.Router.map(function() {
       this.resource('profile', {path: 'profile/:profile_id'})
   })
   ```
2. Yes, you must describe one-to-many relation between Employee and Feedback models, if you want to access 'feedbacks' list from Employee model.

**Update:**
If you want to decouple Feedback model from Employee, you can move that relation between them from models to controller.

It might look like:

```
App.ProfileController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
    feedbackList: function() {
        return this.store.find('feedback', { employee: this.get('model.id') });
    }.property('model.id')
});
```

Use that field (`feedbackList`) in a template:

```
{{#each feedback in feedbackList}}
    {{feedback.text}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: But wouldn't that require me to have a list of feedbacks at employees in my fixtures?

Comment: It would require an array of feedback ids (ex. `feedbacks: [1,2,3]`) corresponding to ids from Feedback's fixtures.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid this? I want to set things up so that Employee doesn't have to know about Feedback.

Comment: We can manipulate data in any way we need, of course. But construction like 'employee.feedbacks' tells us about connection between 'employee' and 'feedback' pretty straight. :)

Comment: I get that, and it's a pretty logical way of organizing models. My problem is that now whoever can add new feedback practicly has the right to edit employees. So now on the back end I have to build an auth structure where writing permissions aren't restricted to which table someone can edit, but which fileds in each table.

**From ember perspective** you're absolutely right though :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67737/discussion-between-fonorobert-and-microfed).